# Stuck on Data Integration Specialist badge 7 step

Tags: integration, callout, trailhead, superbadges

Here is what it says:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:  There was an
>   unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check
>   from completing: System.CalloutException: IO Exception: External
>   server did not return any content

Tried on different orgs, but without success.
Even tried from scratch with the guide http://ashishkeshari.com/index.php/2017/03/01/superbadge-data-integration-specialist/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Data Integration Specialist Superbadge - Step 7 issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/185083/102), there appears to be an issue with the web service returning:

```
{"timestamp":1500520484619,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error",
 "exception":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError","message":"unable to create new native thread","path":"/ws"}
```

Rather than the expected SOAP response. Or even a valid SOAP fault message.

You will need to wait for the Trailhead team to address this issue.

**Update** The service now appears to be returning a valid response.