# Data Integration Specialist Superbadge - Step 7 issue

Tags: trailhead, superbadges

Data Integration Specialist Superbadge - Step 7

Step 7 - Synchronize Salesforce project data with Square Peg's external billing system

I'm getting an error message when triggering the SOAP call from the UI via record update:

> System.CalloutException: IO Exception: External server did not return any content

When I import the WSDL into SOAP UI and send the same package body, I receive this message:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 
Server: Cowboy
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 10 Jul 2017 17:58:08 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid SOAP response. SOAP is XML based, so the JSON in the Content-Type is a strong indication that something isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

Being a superbadge, particularly one that is now tied to an Salesforce University credential, I'm reluctant to give the full details of how to pass this challenge.

I can confirm that I got a very similar response from the web service when testing it from SOAP UI:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 20 Jul 2017 03:14:44 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

{"timestamp":1500520484619,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error",
 "exception":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError","message":"unable to create new native thread","path":"/ws"}
```

That JSON response seems to be particularly relevant. Is suspect there is something broken on their end. I've [reached out](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/887943957941858304) to the Trailhead team about this. You could also use the feedback link provided directly in Trailhead.

I'd suggest focusing on the automated test cases and ensuring that they assert the correct outcomes.

---

**Update**

Just tried exactly the same request again today, it is looking much healthier.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Soapaction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 282
Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2017 21:59:38 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:billProjectResponse xmlns:ns2="http://salesforce.com/th/invoice-web-service"><ns2:status>ok</ns2:status></ns2:billProjectResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```